# Java - How to check if a abstract superclass is a particular subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

The question might look trivial but I couldn't find the solution anywhere!

I have an abstract superclass `Vehicle`, and there are 4 subclasses that extend it, viz `Car`, `Bus`, `Lorry` and `Bicycle`.

I also have an `ArrayList<Vehicle> V` containing many `Vehicle` objects but we don't know which type of vehicle.

Now I am not able to calculate the number of `Cars` in the `ArrayList V`

```
int carCount = 0;
for (Vehicle ob: V){
    if (ob is a car) {
        carCount++;
        }
    }
return carCount;
```

Would like to know what should be the code inside `if(ob is a car)` in the code above.

Thanks!

Comment: `if(ob instanceof Car)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(ob instanceof Car)
```

Please try this

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one line, if you use java-8:

```
V.stream().filter(Car.class::isInstance).count();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for

```
if (ob instanceof Car) {
    carCount++;
}
```

Get detailed information here: [Oracle: instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)